# Serial data over time into an array and then plotting a graph?

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to take serial data that is being sent at a frequency of about 1hz.  After a defined time I would like to plot the accumulated data.  I have been searching the web and I really cant find much help.  I have a few books on the way and was hoping for someone's input on how I could go about doing this.  Thanks for any help in advance.

```
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import datetime


ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate = 115200, timeout=1)
def myfast():
    buffer = []
    val = ser.readline().strip('lbf\r\n')
    buffer.append(val)
    n = 100
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(n): myfast()
    t1 = time.time()

total_n = t1-t0
x = [datetime.datetime.now()]
y = [buffer]


plt.plot(x,y)

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
print(buffer)
```

Comment: return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
this is the error I get in the current code

Comment: I can view the data sent to the computer, the strip takes the unit lbf out as well as the \r\n.

Comment: The end result that I would like is a graph over the time period that I create.  This would be a pressure graph coming from a gauge.  After I can get it working on a time, I will work on the GUI with a start and end button.

Comment: I can successfully save the data into a file in the format of :
26 Jan 2017
09:07:05
 20.0 lbf
26 Jan 2017
09:07:06
 20.0 lbf
26 Jan 2017
09:07:06
 20.0 lbf
26 Jan 2017
09:07:06
 20.0 lbf
from this I can plot a graph after my timeframe is done, I would only want to use the time stamp and the force for the graph, I'm not finding much on how to separate a single column with 3 repeating rows of data. This post makes it look like a big string, but my files has it separated into one ling column

Comment: 0        1      2        3            4         5   6
0   40.0      lbf  100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:14 NaN
1   40.0      lbf  100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:14 NaN
2   40.0      lbf  100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15 NaN
3   40.0      lbf  100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15 NaN
4   40.0      lbf  100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15 NaN
5   40.0      lbf  100.0      lbf  30 Jan 2017  13:07:15 NaN
I have the data format to this.  I keep getting float errors when I try and graph it!? Help!

Comment: pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default') 
pd.set_option('display.line_width', 5000) 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 60) 
force = pd.read_csv(open('press.csv','rU'), encoding='utf-8', engine='c', header=None)
force.columns = ["presst", "units", "pressm", "units2", "date", "time", "nothin"]

#plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
#plt.xticks( rotation= 80 )
#ax=plt.gca()
#xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
#ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
#plt.figure()
#for i in range(len('presst')):
#    plt.plot('time'[i], 'presst'[i])



#plt.show()

print(force)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using pandas to label the array and plot the program.